# Canvas onClick binding doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i'm developing a canvas-based timeline.
I want to trigger the onClick event to get informations about the clicked element.

```
canvas.onclick = function(e){
  var evt = e || event;
  var x = evt.offsetX;
  var y = evt.offsetY;

  for(var i=0;i<items_loaded.length;i++){
    var item = items_loaded[i];
    alert(x + ' | ' + y);
    if((x > item['x_start'] && x < item['x_end']) && (y > item['y_start'] && y < item['y_end'])){
      alert('Trovata fermata con ID: ' + item['id']);
    }
  }
}
```

I checked the code and the event seems to not fire right.

Comment: I take it you are trying to click things that are drawn onto the canvas and get information about said things?

Comment: Yeah, i'm trying to do this...

Comment: So canvasing is a little fancy in that it only knows what colors it is drawing onto itself. There are no 'elements' to click on per say. Is this supposed to be a dynamic system or static? If it is static I have one idea that could work using Image Maps instead of canvasing which you could then overlay a canvas on top of. If it is dynamic then you are gonna need some function to calculate where you clicked in relation to pixel positions of drawn shapes and make a decision based on what shape you 'clicked' on, it's a weird concept